# Is it possible to extract all the text appearing in video using it's metadata?

Tags: video, text

Example: If I have a recorded news channel video or a video which contains text like static, motion etc., then is it possible to extract every text from the video from it's metadata?

Comment: You need example pictures (3 different frames) to show us what you mean... PS: You don't extract video's text from metadata (unless you mean subtitles and they've been put in the metadata). If the words exist on the screen (as part of the frame's picture) then either you need a **template image** or you need **OCR**. Depends on your input (need to show it) and also tell us your input video's format (or file type).